# Is every injective rational function $f:\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q$ a polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, rational-numbers, rational-functions

I thought this might be quite easy to show, and then realized that the tools I know from real analysis aren't going to help here.

Suppose we have a rational function:

$$
f(X)=\frac{P(X)}{Q(X)}
$$

where $Q$ has no linear factors over $\mathbb Q$ (so $Q(x)=0$ if $x\in\mathbb Q$).  Now suppose that $f$ is an injection when considered as a function $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q$.  Must we have $Q=1$; i.e., $f$ is a polynomial?

The only way I could think of to study injectivity algebraically was the following: since $f$ is injective, we have that if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$.  Now treat $x$ and $y$ as invariants; that is to say, take the expression:

$$
\frac{P(X)}{Q(X)}=\frac{P(Y)}{Q(Y)}\\
P(X)Q(Y)=P(Y)Q(X)\\
P(X)Q(Y)-P(Y)Q(X)=0
$$

Now the only solution to $P(x)Q(y)-P(y)Q(x)$ over the rationals is $x=y$ (since $f$ is injective).  This means that the expression $P(X)Q(Y)-P(Y)Q(X)$ is the product of $(X-Y)$ and an irreducible; i.e.:

$$
P(X)Q(Y)-P(Y)Q(X)=(X-Y)R(X,Y)
$$

where $R\in\mathbb Q[X,Y]$ is irreducible.

I don't really know where to go from here.  Is this the right sort of argument?

Comment: Why would $R(X,Y)$ be irreducible, rather than just having that $R(x,y)\neq 0$ for $x\neq y\in\mathbb Q$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isn't 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^3+3}$$

a counter example?

A "non-trivial" example would be

$$f(x)=\frac{ax^3}{x^3+3}$$

It is easy to see that this is injective when $a \neq 0$ since it can be written as

$$f(x)=a-\frac{3a}{x^3+3}$$

Moreover, as $f(x)$ is decreasing as a real valued function, if $P(x)$ is any polinomial with $P'<0$ then

$$g(x)=P(x)+\frac{1}{x^3+3}$$
satisfies the requirements.

Comment: Yes it is.  I think I might have to reformulate the question, but thanks.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 I added a modification of the example below, keep that in mind when you try to reformulate the question.